# Is it normal for Docker to create so many mounts and not clean them up?

Tags: filesystems, docker, mount

I've recently provisioned a server with Ubuntu 14.10 and Docker CE using the overlay2 storage driver. After running a few containers my `df -h` output looks like this:

```
root@dev1:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G   12G  7.2G  62% /
devtmpfs        492M     0  492M   0% /dev
tmpfs           495M     0  495M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           495M  9.4M  486M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           495M     0  495M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c8a64b3d90888c734f0ac8b6854cabfdcf238e716f39080450a5abd85b5e371b/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/250094a88d3d6f3af5dbc3cf93636e382092e160c944f02c5008d07909f7a620/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9222282cf5f4274f50623b02c07e6863442cdb385117a3c9b1a98e52273af8ad/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/465d0f2a73f9005dbea7281b9fa0b553c3e99e49107b250172fade3764052e5a/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/4f6340df52e9828bfc8d7c70a95ad6f8e7d9204a7a718ed4f72b9f6e91cc075a/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/46cd1080275a6a3f649330cfdff69e03ff8099fb31d81b736f3ffdc447c8a375/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a8ffd7344def30e0bde1caa80c0597c51663e3684b5e8deb4deb9ecf1395aea2/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/e40bd327b2ad3017d7350b1817de1d58cba42993eaa5dc4db5259a66fae29e44/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2520e792b3e86f6da1f8ece8b68cf5cea1f25c5da219fce579fc2a142d381af4/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/b1f626492cc5ae1ad241f521f11279705740261fbda71e38c134be61c3247830/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c4cb8bb4bb444272db2172c6409514d61a443ae26ce18b4b87b9e2813f60758e/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/6566daf418ccd3021410719c29aa202041769749ae027f3ee2f0db431613a547/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/832ebb7c4641ef2cdb0708418110c400a63324cf2b4a489da2a4fcf565a00de1/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/8be7d0b8c449377fe51a5d581d438e07136e776ba67a434b5fe9338691afc811/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b48976d701f72245535d00035c31f67c06b163a6adf3cfa0aa65d7d9d635be76/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/1562126d1a41675f66ed4fa06885d81ef9f629ecb26905670d0a1ba547f34b37/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/54a7a1647e89b61bb1f43a29a9ca20e082efa834c062c9c92da84ac301637eb0/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/2b069b9034223177fda4fd28a56b1d5efa32f1b9206e051c8b1e0f7a8bc18349/shm
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/0
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2bf5497b1743bf260cfb8e3619d8587a3b47f46633f3a8704ec1ef7a0725541a/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/8dcc013097a7a20f4c0b5833bb5b3d256876528c22d3484f849d52b55a6eb44a/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/8a8a920c984ca0db9da745647900b3020fac173442bf268110ba06938be755b2/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/817a36bea3f79610b04d7ade9d16c122c30f7ff981996d17e556c95f16c5c102/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cd3e9dad0a7e6e9eaadf10816c4bd4e3fc0fb0134264c43aaac47da192c2933a/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/0af08a186eaa6d42c89af4728fb66b48ab32350fab0e19d68c7916c753255a45/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/fd0e0505f9112f5ee239f06f7833694d37c9b473dc32bd1d367fb8042af75198/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/0270c05504523225206f37e85dca3915ca68def7a1e0aa148e5be0124a845b0e/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/17f2a5db405350215cc432ff21f88acc699e8dbd879d1e3edb4bb40e0d9d09e2/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/0d9f0ce27b16363262cc9735734d3332c9e356c8aef1bf2a4a1ff05b085b231f/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/44aae49e079d49db1447e09806ed8c697f25ac056d64325937c2d7e2cf9598f7/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/8108b6034e92ec0e1f7d90785c907148d5d2950be4b0573fc470c2587fb68337/shm
overlay          20G   12G  7.2G  62% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b7da3582b33c6b8d72ff7af6295b653484e97877502abcf1f5b83dce25ac3c41/merged
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/d707a2374f92f056b0ba1055a0055316f67a4300b73e0646204f8cf206f0de28/shm
```

Even when I do `docker system prune` to clear everything these mount points just don't go. I seem to be gathering more and more of them and there's no obvious way to get rid of them.

**Is this normal/expected behaviour?**

`docker info`:

```
Containers: 16
 Running: 14
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 16
Server Version: 17.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 4ab9917febca54791c5f071a9d1f404867857fcc
runc version: 54296cf40ad8143b62dbcaa1d90e520a2136ddfe
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.15-x86_64-linode81
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.10
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 989 MiB
Name: dev1
ID: KWTP:NAOT:CGDG:HBCS:UOVG:H3XZ:IW7C:5EJA:IZI7:ROFZ:EHHU:TQNL
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Docker installation script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install packages to allow apt to access a repository over https
sudo apt-get -y install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common

# Add Dockers official GPG key
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

# Verify that the key fingerprint is 9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88

# Set up the stable repository
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"

# Update the apt package index.
sudo apt-get update

# Latest version of Docker
sudo apt-get -y install docker-ce

# Configure Docker FileSystem
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
cat > /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/overlay2.conf <<EOF
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --storage-driver=overlay2
EOF

# Add users to docker group
usermod -aG docker $(whoami)
usermod -aG docker $SUDO_USER

reboot
```

Comment: How do you start the containers ? Did you have tried to remove it ?

Comment: The containers are started through Rancher, which may be a complication but unlikely.

Comment: I can remove all the containers, images and volumes using the standard docker commands and still these mount points do not disappear.

Comment: Are you using any kind of persistent-storage feature (Rancher or otherwise?)

Comment: No, nothing fancy like that

Comment: One of the containers is a CI runner that uses docker in docker.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Containers: 16
>  Running: 14
>  Paused: 0
>  Stopped: 2
> ```

These mounts are used by running containers. In your info it appears you have 14 running containers. A prune command will not stop and delete running containers, so that isn't expected to cleanup these mounts. To remove the mount you need to stop and delete the container. Use:

```
docker container ls # list containers
docker container stop $container_id # stop the container
docker container rm $container_id # delete the container
```

Note that deleting a container deletes all logs, configuration of that container, and anything written to the container filesystem. It will not delete volumes unless the volume is an anonymous volume and the container is started with the `--rm` option.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same issue recently on Ubuntu 20.04 with Docker v19.03.13. I searched through Docker docs and found that this maybe because of a new type of filesystem they introduced. You can read more about it from [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/). The way I fixed it was by editing (creating if not present already) the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file and adding the following lines:

```
{
  "storage-driver": "overlay"
}
```

Then restarting docker using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: Restarting the docker engine stopped your running containers. That by itself will remove those mounts.

Comment: @BMitch Yes, but after some time those mounts can reappear if you start running your containers. But changing the storage driver will prevent it from using overlay2 as the default filesystem, so it won't mount again!

Comment: overlay (v1) is old and unlikely to be supported. V2 fixed various stability issues.